# CakePHP "with" method in mock object don't Work

Tags: cakephp, authentication, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying testing my application using CakePHP 2.2 RC1, in the certain action of my controller i need one information of Auth object, in my test i have created an mock object for the Auth component, but when i call the method **with** my mock object become invalid, when i don't put this everything works fine.

Below the mock object wich dont work

```
$this->controller->Auth
    ->staticExpects($this->any())
    ->method('user')
    ->with('count_id')
    ->will($this->returnValue(9));
```

Thanks for your attention guys.

--

**Edit**

Above the full code of my test case, this a very simple test.

```
class TagsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public function testView(){
        $Tags = $this->generate('Tags', array(
            'components' => array(
                'Session',
                'Auth' => array('user')
            )
        ));
        $Tags->Auth->staticExpects($this->any())
            ->method('user')
            ->with('count_id')
            ->will($this->returnValue(2));

        $result = $this->testAction('/tags/view');
        $this->assertEquals($result, 2);
    }
}
```

And the code of my action in the Tag controller, this don't have nothing more (for testing purposes) them a return of user object with count_id as parameter.

```
public function view(){
    return $this->Auth->user('count_id');
}
```

Running the test I received this message:

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked zero or more times
>   Parameter 0 for invocation AuthComponent::user(null) does not match expected value.
>   Failed asserting that null matches expected 'count_id'.

Comment: What does your test method look like? What about your `setUp()`?

Comment: Hi, my method verify if user can do the action based in the count which her is associate. If a run the test with the code above the test suit return **Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:user> when invoked zero or more times
Parameter 0 for invocation AuthComponent::user(null) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that null matches expected 'count_id'.**, you make any idea of what can cause this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of your test method, the method you're testing and your setUp() if available, it is difficult to say what's going on without seeing the code. Looking at your error message, it seems like there is a call to user() somewhere that you're missing (in a component perhaps?)

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I've edited the post with the full code of my test case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the `AuthComponent` code, I think the problem lies in the fact that you're not mocking the entire component *or* you're not mocking the `_getUser()` method. Don't forget: **the methods you're not mocking are *real* methods!**

If you look at the code you'll see that `user()` is called by `_getUser()` which in turn is called by `startup()`.

There are two ways to solve this problem, the first is to mock the entire `AuthComponent`:

```
$Tags = $this->generate('Tags', array(
        'components' => array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' /* no methods */
        )
    ));
```

or mock `_getUser()` in addition to `user()`:

```
$Tags = $this->generate('Tags', array(
        'components' => array(
            'Session',
            'Auth' => array('user', '_getUser')
        )
    ));
```

Hopefully, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue which I could not solve by the solution provided.

The solution is to use staticExpects() instead of expects() as user is a static function.

```
$batches->Auth->staticExpects($this->once())->method('user') 
        ->with('id')
        ->will($this->returnValue(1));
```