# CakePHP “with” method in mock object returns a null value

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I am facing the exact problem as this question.
[CakePHP "with" method in mock object don't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111383/cakephp-with-method-in-mock-object-dont-work)

But the answer provided is not working for me either.

Here's the issue.
Controller test case code:

```
public function testCreate() {
$batches = $this->generate('ShippingBatches', array(
    'components' => array(
        'Session', 
        'Auth' => array('user', '_getUser')
        )
)); 

$batches->Auth->expects($this->once())->method('user') 
    ->with('id') 
    ->will($this->returnValue(1));

$batches->Session
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('setFlash');

$this->testAction('/shippingbatches/create', array('data' => '[3,6]', 'method' => 'post'));
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public function create(){
//Some code here
$d['ShippingBatch']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->ShippingBatch->save($d);
//some code here
}
```

The error:
**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null
Test case: ShippingBatchesControllerTestCase(testCreate)**

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use staticExpects() instead of expects() as user is a static function.

```
$batches->Auth->staticExpects($this->once())->method('user') 
        ->with('id')
        ->will($this->returnValue(1));
```